# Block Transaction if it is over a certain amount

Tags: transactions, wallet, bitcoind, security, sendtoaddress

Is there a way to block a transaction if the transaction exceeds a certain amount of BTC. I am running bitcoind.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Do you mean to stop yourself from creating such a transaction that spends your own funds? Do you mean to block other people's transactions? Or what?

Comment: so lets say my environment get compromised. I want to place a block to ensure they would not be able to create a large transaction.

Comment: Why would several small transactions not be just as damaging? And if they compromise your environment, wouldn't they just take the key material out of the environment so your equipment would never even see the transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Block another person from having their transaction confirmed if it exceeds a certain amount you chose? No. As long as it doesn't violate any consensus rules, you can't do that. Unless, of course, you fork yourself off the network.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mempool filter or policy to reject such transactions, however they will be included in blocks and present in mempool of other nodes.

Comment: is there any documentation on how to do this?